# unable to get the docker interpreter in pycharm (running in windows 10)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

Currently running docker desktop 2.5.0.1 in windows 10 ,I am trying to configure docker interpreter for my Django project in Pycharm , but I couldn't find any docker interpreter in the left hand side of the window.

I have already added the Django plugins required for pycharm

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker interpreter is PyCharm Professional feature. I don't think you'll find it in community edition

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html